# Integers containing all ten digits

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, number-property

It is known that most positive integers contain at least one copy of each of the ten digits.

What is the largest *n* such that at most 50% of the integers in the set [1,2,3,...,*n*]
contain at least one copy of each of the ten digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First we need a way to count two things: the number of $n$-digit pandigital numbers and the number of pandigital numbers with a given prefix *not* using $r$ digits and a suffix of $f$ "free" digits. The count for the first is $$9\cdot9!S(n,10)$$ where $S(a,b)$ is the second-kind Stirling number, the number of ways to partition $a$ items into $b$ non-empty subsets (we multiply by $9$ for the leading digit choice and by $9!$ for the remaining digit choices). The count for the second is $$\sum_{k=r}^f\binom fkr!S(k,r)(10-r)^{f-k}$$ where $k$ represents the number of "free" digits reserved for non-prefix digits.

> Given the two formulas above we can count the number of pandigital numbers $P(n)$ in $[1,n]$ by considering $n$'s prefixes decremented (so as not to overshoot $n$). Then define the non-pandigital abundance $a(n)=n-2P(n)$; it has the Lipschitz property of $|a(n+1)-a(n)|=1$ and we seek the last zero of $a(n)$. Writing code for $P(n)$ is a very delicate task; the code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Parcly-Taxel/d84d42135507bdc463f7c06429b2d769).

> Knowing the Lipschitz property I first computed $a(n)$ for $n=d\cdot10^{26},1\le d\le10$ to get bounds for *a* zero, specifically the zero's first digit. Then I essentially performed $10$-fold multisection to get additional digits, until I saw all $10$ digits, at which point $a(n)$ was monotone in an interval, positive at the left end and negative at the right. The exact zero followed directly.

The answer is

> **245836727707164139860503406**

> How can this be shown as the last zero of $a(n)$? By using the Lipschitz property, but this is tedious and I will not go over it here. Instead I got confirmation from [OEIS A260900](https://oeis.org/A260900), which includes this number and equivalents of it in other bases. Note in particular the comment "The $27$-digit number $245836727707164139860503406$, which is $a(134)$, is the only term in the $n=10$ row."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with incomplete logic (and could possibly be wrong).

The largest $n$ is

> $1062880$.

Consider the numbers $0$ to $10^m-1$.

> If we think of all of them as $n$-digit numbers (e.g., when $m=3$, $1$ is considered as $001$), then there is an equal number of integers containing at least one copy of each of the ten digits by symmetry. But this largely overestimates the number of integers containing $0$, which means that the number of integers containing $0$ is way less than the number of integers containing copies of other nine digits. Thus, $0$ won't be the "limiting digit".

> Next, we want to find a rough range of where this largest $n$ lies. We can do that by counting the number of integers containing a specific digit in the range $0$ to $10^m-1$. Take the digit $1$ as an example. To count the number of integers containing $1$, we first count the *opposite*, i.e., the number of integers that doesn't contain $1$. If every integer is written as an $n$-digit number, then the integers not containing $1$ can have $0,2,3,\cdots 9$ as its digits, so there are $9^m$ such integers. Hence, the number of integers that *does* contain $1$ is $10^m-9^m$.

> When $m$ is too big (in fact, when $m\geq 7$), $\dfrac{10^m-9^m}{10^m}$ becomes larger than $\dfrac{1}{2}$, meaning that over half of the integers in $0$ to $10^m-1$ now contains $1$. Thus, the largest $n$ possible must lie between $10^6$ and $10^7$. (I think the conclusion here is correct, but there is a lot more justification needed to explain why all $n$ values above $10^7$ won't work, as currently we have only proved the cases where $n=10^x$ and $n\geq 10^7$. I wasn't able to come up with a rigid proof for this)

Now that we have a range where the largest $N$ lies, we can start to track down the exact value of the largest $n$.

> After $10^m-1$, the next $10^m$ numbers all start with $1$. Thus, the "concentration" of numbers containing $1$ rapidly increases. Between $0$ and $2\cdot 10^m-1$, at least $10^m$ integers contain the digit $1$, which is already larger than $\frac{1}{2}$. But for smaller values of $m$ ($m<6$), we know that the number of integers containing $1$ between $0$ and $10^{m+1}-1$ is less than half. Thus, there must have been some kind of "dilution", reducing the "concentration" of integers containing the digit $1$ below $0.5$. However, the effect of this "dilution" is limited for larger $m$ ($m>7$), where the "concentration" of integers containing the digit $1$ stays above $0.5$.

> Here is a draft figure for the concentration of the number of integers containing the digit $1$ for $n$ from $10^6$ to $10^7$. [image]

> Now our objective is pretty clear: to find the point of intersection between the blue curve and the horizontal dotted line representing concentration $=0.5$.

> How many integers containing $1$ are there from $0$ to $10^6-1$? We've answered that question above, and the answer is $10^6-9^6=468559.$ Let the largest $n$ be $(10^6-1)+x$, where $x<10^6$. Then the number of integers containing the digit $1$ is $468559+x$. Thus the concentration of integers containing the digit $1$ can be expressed as $\dfrac{468559+x}{10^6-1+x}$. When does this concentration equals $0.5$? We just need to solve the equation $\dfrac{468559+x}{10^6-1+x}=\dfrac{1}{2}$.  The result is that $x=62881$. Thus, the largest $n$ is $10^6-1+x=1062880$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is about pandigital numbers - a pandigital number is one that contains every digit at least once. Pandigital numbers are by definition at least 10 digits long. The question asks for the highest $n$ such that no more than 50% of the numbers $1$ to $n$ are pandigital.

Comment: @JaapScherpuis see my answer.